# How to stop auto backup in some directory in Emacs

Tags: directory-local-variables, backup

In general I want Emacs to save a backup file for me, except in some special directories.

I tried to define a [Directory Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html), and add:

```
((nil . ((make-backup-files . nil))))
```

But it seem it won't take effect. I think it is because `make-backup-files` is a global variable.

Is there a equivalent local variable to control the backup creation function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backup decisions seem to pass through the function `normal-backup-enable-predicate`, via the variable `backup-enable-predicate` which is set to this by default. You can provide your own function to return `nil` if no backup is to be done. 
For example,

```el
(defun my-backup-enable-predicate (name)
  (let (found)
    (dolist (specialdir '("/somedir/" "/some/other/") found)
      (if (string-prefix-p specialdir name)
          (setq found t)))
    (if found
        nil
      (normal-backup-enable-predicate name))))

(setq backup-enable-predicate #'my-backup-enable-predicate)
```

This tests if the provided full pathname begins with one of the listed directories (`/somedir/` or `/some/other/` in this example) and if so returns nil, otherwise calls the usual backup test function.  The final line make emacs use your function. To go back to the real function use

```el
(setq backup-enable-predicate #'normal-backup-enable-predicate)
```

---

I reread your question and realised I hadn't answered it. To allow you to set `make-backup-files` in your `.dir-locals.el` I think all you need is to make it buffer local in your startup file:

```el
(make-variable-buffer-local 'make-backup-files)
```

The documentation says "Buffer-local bindings are normally cleared
while setting up a new major mode, unless they have a 'permanent-local'
property.". You can set this property with

```el
(put 'make-backup-files 'permanent-local 't)
```

Comment: This is not what I want...but seems to be the closest I could get. Thx~

Comment: @davidshen84 Sorry, I think I had forgotten the important part of your question when I got round to my answer. I think there is a much simpler solution available for you, see updated answer.

Comment: I found `make-variable-buffer-local` do not work for me. I have to use `make-local-variable`. Any idea?

Comment: @davidshen84 Perhaps the major-mode is clearing the buffer-local binding, as mentioned in the doc. See the new last line in my answer for how to set a property to avoid this (in your startup file).