# Disable auto-backup only for certain files

Tags: file-local-variables, backup

As of [How to stop auto backup in some directory in Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22245/how-to-stop-auto-backup-in-some-directory-in-emacs), it's possible to configure emacs to backup conditionally.

Is there an option to set *inside the file*, [in the first line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html), to disable backup for this file only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, simply set `make-backup-files` to `nil` locally, for example,

```
M-x add-file-local-variable-prop-line make-backup-files nil
```

Comment: which creates a line with a comment character and then `-*- make-backup-files: nil; -*-` Thank you very much, even a command for easy creation